# Trouble Self-hosting a chrome app

Tags: google-chrome, host

I've built a Google Chrome Web App for my blog and want to host it on 000webhost. I have a direct link to the .crx file and when the user clicks it, it downloads the file and tries to install, however they get this error: "Apps must be served with content type application/x-chrome-extension". Now after doing much research, I still am not sure how to fix this, I tried adding a meta tag to the head section of the page with the link, I then tried using a PHP header on the page with the link

```
header('Content-Type: application/x-chrome-extension');
```

However that did not work either, I then tried adding this line of code to the top of my .htaccess code:

```
AddType application/x-chrome-extension crx
```

And you guessed it, it didn't work. I'd really appreciate some help with this, I don't want to pay the $5 just yet, I want to see if people think that it's worth bothering with the app, but I can only do that if my users can download the app!

PS, I get the same error message every time.

Comment: If you run `curl -v --head http://example.com/extension.crx` is the `Content-Type` set as expected?

Comment: I found out that this error only appears on some computers and not on others but I haven't managed to find the common denominator yet. Still wouldn't mind help :)

Comment: On linux/osx you run curl commands in the terminal. On windows follow these instructions: http://superuser.com/questions/134685/run-curl-commands-from-windows-console